# Use custom regex to validate linkedIn url

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to normalize linkedin urls. For that I am using regex `^https:\/\/[w]{3}\.linkedin\.com\/.*$` which needs to change according to new requirement.
The only valid patterns are:

- `https://www.linkedin.com/in/XXXXXX-XXXXX-55301b41`
- `https://www.linkedin.com/pub/XXXXXX-XXXXX-55301b41`
- `https://www.linkedin.com/public-profile/in/XXXXXX-XXXX-b82a7b10a`
- `https://www.linkedin.com/public-profile/pub/XXXXXX-XXXX-b82a7b10a`

Few bad corner cases are:

- `https://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxx-xxxx-ab85a328/%7Bcountry%3Dde%2C+language%3Dde%7D?trk=people-guest_profile-result-card_result-card_full-click`
- `https://www.linkedin.com/edu/school?id=18987`
- `https://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxx-xxxx-55301b41/de`
- `https://www.linkedin.com/pub/xxxxx-xxxxx/98/b7a/22b`
- `https://it.linkedin.com/public-profile/in/xxxx-xxxxx-80520667?challengeId=AQEV3tHveORYsAAAAXQqx1N3bZ7fd44s5ngegJp6rC0UoWvhG2LtAhhgld8h3QyBxorfcLL2iuvK4xh_UKoGguxvX6sFx_nnZA&submissionId=7bc972ed-bfd1-2e16-c395-ad35cb550117`

The logics would be:

- must start with https://www.linkedin.com/
- must have /in/, /pub/, /public-profile/in/, /public-profile/pub
- should end with username i.e XXXXXX-XXXXX-55301b41

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples only, could you please try following regex. Online demo of regex is: [Online demo of regex](https://regex101.com/r/oJ5j7j/2)

```
^http[s]?:\/\/www\.linkedin\.com\/(in|pub|public-profile\/in|public-profile\/pub)\/([\w]{6}-[\w]{1,}-[\w]+)$
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^http[s]?:                    ##Checking if URL starts from http OR https.
\/\/www\.linkedin\.com\/      ##Then checking if domain is www.linkedin.com
(in|pub|public-profile\/in|public-profile\/pub)  ##Then checking if its followed by in OR pub OR public-profile/in OR public-profile/pub
\/([\w]{6}-[\w]{1,}-[\w]+)$   ##Checking if above is followed by / [\w] with 6 occurrences - [\w] with 1 or more occurrences and then [\w] with 1 or more occurrences.
```

***NOTE:*** In case you want to check url should only start with https then change `^http[s]?` TO `^https` in above regex.

***NOTE2:*** Above will create 2 capturing groups, in case you don't want to create any capturing groups try following.

```
^http[s]?:\/\/www\.linkedin\.com\/(?:in|pub|public-profile\/in|public-profile\/pub)\/(?:[\w]{6}-[\w]{1,}-[\w]+)$
```

[Regex demo for note2 regex](https://regex101.com/r/oJ5j7j/3)

Comment: One gotcha though is that the third level domain may not always be `www`, I believe for Canadians, for example, it would be `ca.linkedin.com`

Comment: FYI, putting a backslash on the end of the url breaks your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a regex for the complete string, try using a url parser first, then validate the scheme, netloc, and path separately

```py
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.urlparse("https://www.linkedin.com/in/XXXXXX-XXXXX-55301b41")
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.linkedin.com', path='/in/XXXXXX-XXXXX-55301b41', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urllib.parse.urlparse("https://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxx-xxxx-ab85a328/%7Bcountry%3Dde%2C+language%3Dde%7D?trk=people-guest_profile-result-card_result-card_full-click")
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.linkedin.com', path='/in/xxxx-xxxx-ab85a328/%7Bcountry%3Dde%2C+language%3Dde%7D', params='', query='trk=people-guest_profile-result-card_result-card_full-click', fragment='')
```

component validation

```py
>>> parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse("https://www.linkedin.com/in/XXXXXX-XXXXX-55301b41")
>>> parsed_url.scheme == "https"
True
>>> parsed_url.netloc.endswith(".linkedin.com")
True
```